# Trying to loop marker data into maps api from mySQL results in "Invalid shorthand property initializer"

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to loop the data from my mySQL database into markersData to produce pins on google's map. the manually entered data above my loop statement works when I remove the php but I cannot get the map to show with the loop.

```
var markersData = [
    {
        lat: 40.6247167,
        lng: -8.7129167,
        name: "Camping Gafanha da Nazaré",
        time:"Rua Diogo Cão, 125"
    },
    <?
    $query ="SELECT * FROM `locations` WHERE `USER`='$user' ORDER BY TIME DESC";
    $result = $conn->query($query);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $mrklat =$row["MRKLAT"];
            $mrklng =$row["MRKLNG"];
            $Time =$row["TIME"];
            $test[] ='{ lat="' . $row['MRKLAT'] . '", lng="' . $row['MRKLNG'] . '" }';
        }
        //Doesn't comma last item
        echo implode(',', $test);
    }
    ?>
];
```

Here's the output of the query if I just output it into a webpage to make it easier for you to check syntax:

```
{ lat="53.218278", lng="-0.547646" },{ lat="53.218278", lng="-0.547646" }
```

Comment: You have equal signs instead of colons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
$test[] ='{ lat="' . $row['MRKLAT'] . '", lng="' . $row['MRKLNG'] . '" }';
```

To:

```
$test[] ='{ lat:"' . $row['MRKLAT'] . '", lng:"' . $row['MRKLNG'] . '" }';
```